# Using a single adapter to display items from two separate classes

Tags: java, android

I have extended an ArrayAdapter that displays items from two separate classes together in one `ListView`.  I pass in `ArrayList<ClassA> classAList` and `ArrayList<ClassB> classBList` to the constructor and an update method, and have overridden the supporting functions to display the two classes differently.  Having done this, it seems somewhat inelegant.

Is there a more native way to combine multiple classes into a single ListView?

Comment: Create an interface containing getters for the elements you want displayed and either have `classA` and `classB` implement it or create wrappers for them. You will need to be more specific (ie post code) if you want an answer containing sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not elegant because `ListView` is not designed to show complex data and layouts, your method was pretty much one can do.

If you want to show multiple cell template in an elegant way, you should use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).

It's very similar with `ListView`, you need to implement an adapter which serves as a data source and cell's View factory. Specifically, look at [getItemViewType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)), [createViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#createViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup,%20int)) and [bindViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#bindViewHolder(VH,%20int)).

[Or just search for an solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can do it by few **dirty** ways.

The first option is to wrap these classes to a single class that will hold references to *ClassA* and *ClassB*. After that, you can work with it like with a normal object.

The second option is to work with both lists at the same time, but you need to work in the adapter in a different way.

First:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return classAList.size() + classBList.size();
}
```

Second

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if(position >= classAList.size()){
         return classBList.get(position  -  classAList.size());
    }
    return classAList.get(position);
}
```

If you will be using same view for both list all other is same otherwise you should *override* few more things:
At least
**getViewTypeCount()** and **getItemViewType()**